# Toshiba Satellite L630 broken after BIOS update

Tags: windows-xp, bios, toshiba-laptop

I have Toshiba Satellite L630, which has been broken. It had no more OS installed in it. All the disk partition were cleared into one single empty unformatted partition. So I begin to install windows XP on this laptop. Apparently, win XP's driver support for this laptop is very limited. So I have to find almost all important driver (display, sound, etherned, wireless etc) on the net and install it manually one by one.

So I start googling, and I got [some](http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/wlan/?page=downloads) [driver](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?modelFilter=&rpn=PSK00U&category=&selCategory=2756709&moid=2901757&os=&ct=DL&selFamily=1073768663) [download](http://toshiba-asia.com/support/drivers) page from several Toshiba's website (the global version, the europe, asia, etc). Pretty hard to find the exact drivers, but I managed to find pretty good drivers. It's all works quite fine, although still have a few glitches.

But everything turned into a big mess when I downloaded the "[BIOS Update](http://eu.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/download_driver_details.jsp?service=EU&selCategory=2&selFamily=2&selSeries=178&selProduct=5390&selShortMod=1030&language=13&selOS=10&selType=all&yearupload=&monthupload=&dayupload=&useDate=null&mode=allMachines&search=&action=search&macId=&country=all&selectedLanguage=13&type=all&page=1&ID=80845&OSID=-1&driverLanguage=42)", which is also listed on Toshiba's official driver directory site. When I installed it, it show a big red warning sign telling me not to do anything while flashing the BIOS . I follow that instruction prudently. The process was finished, and that update BIOS software (it is InsydeH2O BIOS) told me that the BIOS has been succesfully updated and the computer need to restart. So I restart the computer.

This is where the problem appear. I can no longer boot to my laptop. The booting process seems to be able to enter windows for a moment (it shows the windows XP loading screen), and then suddenly it just got that hateful blue screen and then instantiy restarts the machine. It goes on a loop. Boot bios -> enter XP -> blue screen -> restart.

I can't even try to reinstall my win XP again. Evertime the machine tries to boot to win XP CD, it got the same blue screen as I gets when loading from HDD.

Many google search results said that I should open the laptop cover and [try to clear CMOS with some kind of jumper or something](http://www.ehow.com/how_6760776_reset-toshiba-cmos.html). Or to [unplug/re-plug the CMOS battery](http://www.ehow.com/how_5835523_remove-cmos-battery-toshiba-laptop.html). Do I really need to do that? Is there anyway I could do without disassembling my laptop? I read some tricks about booting from USB device but I can't get the exat tools that I need to do that thing...

Btw, this is my detailed laptop number photographed from the back of my laptop
[image: the]

Comment: Can you get to the BIOS settings page (usually F2 or DEL while the self-test is running)?

Comment: yes I can... and I acknowledge that it now use insydeH2O BIOS

Comment: Righty. What about booting an OS other than Windows? A linux liveCD maybe? (I'm thinking something that uses a different graphics card driver, really).

Comment: I tried that... it's able only to enter the built in shell... but no luck at all either to enter GUI mode on liveCD or installation

Comment: Sounds very much then like your BIOS isn't playing nicely with your graphics chipset. Can you access any settings for the display adapter in the BIOS setup?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not so sure.. the only possibly-display-related-setting available on the BIOS is these two: Web camera & Power on Display

Comment: Well, worst-case, you could download your old bios on another computer and flash it back with that? Or the linux liveCD might have lynx in it, if you feel brave...

Comment: that's the problem... I've tried to re-flash my BIOS to its original (using bootable CD/USB). But I can't find any available non-exe BIOS listed on Toshiba's website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on [Toshiba's Forums](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/System-Recovery-and-Recovery/Satellite-L630-broken-after-bios-update/td-p/346578)

It happenned because I was trying to install Windows XP on a SATA drive, but the Setup has no driver for the SATA-drive's controller.